# breaking Muslim Friendships permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, friendship, time

I have a best friend.(same gender)who loves me so much. and I'm the only muslim friend she has. but every single day we spend  total 4 hours chatting about halal but past, childhood and other things . (never gossip). sometimes also learn quran together. our frendship brings good and bad to our akhira. soemtimes one weighs over another. and she doesn't seem to be guilty about spending time too much like this. but I do. is it ok, if I cut ties with her/ block her contact. even though it'll hurt me and her. but it's for the sake of allah. to not waste  away my time talking about usless things.? it really affects my concentration in salah. please advice .

Comment: Whatever thing you do, be it small or big, if it's done just to please your Rabb, then there can be no harm in it. My opinion is if you can find a balance without cutting ties with your Muslim friend, that would be better. Because one's faith is not complete unless you want the best for the other believers as well. Always try to please your Rabb in the best way possible, aim for a greater reward. If to there is no improvement, you can always distant yourself. But first try to reason and come to an understanding for the better with your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. The main purpose of our life is to worship ALLAH (Glory Be To Him).

**Quraan**
*I did not create jinn and humans except to worship Me. (Surah 51 verse 56)*

Now when it comes to friendship it becomes very important to choose our friends wisely.

**Hadith**
The Prophet (ﷺ) said: A man follows the religion of his friend; so each one should consider whom he makes his friend. (Abu Dawud in the chapter of general behavior)

My next words might seems harsh but your friend is not forcing you to have these conversations. Nor does she prevent you from praying or anything. That is something you will have to look at yourself and say what can I do better so that I don't disturb my salah or any other acts of ibadah.

I would suggest not calling her all the time or if she is calling you then perhaps keep the conversation short. All of us sometimes talk about some useless thing here and there but if that is the dominant part of the conversation then bring some useful things in. For example she might be like blah blah blah and you can say hey do you want to go the masjid this weekend. Or perhaps wanna listen to this lecture. Or perhaps want to go play xyz sport, etc.

I will also say don't break relationship but just try to mend them and help the other person as well. Who knows what blessings are hidden between both of your friendship. There is trust there and a good bond between both of you. If you care for her then you will also try to help her not to waste time and try to make her a better person as well.

**Have a nice day!**

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to cut off your friendship. Only your friendship, like anything else in life, should be managed. Everything in life needs planning and management. Sleep, food, entertainment, etc. in narrations in Islam introduce a good friend as a blessing. Sometimes a person needs to talk to a good friend. Have fun.
So try to manage your friendship and your time properly so that you are not harmed.